# How to print letters if their index in the alphabet is in a vector?

Tags: python, string, loops

New with Python.
Let `string` contain all the alphabet.
Let `s` be a string containing a bunch of letters.
Let `v` be a vector with some numbers, or ranged.
I have to print the letters in `s` whose index in the alphabet is contained in `v`.

So far a got a bit of a mess.

```
string = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
v = range(5)
s = "dadalasdfg"

for i in v:
    for j in s:
        if s==string[i] and s[i]==0:
           print (j)
```

Like, given `range(5)`, I want to print 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' if they are contained in `s`.

Comment: I've a problem with the condition your "if": s can't be equal to string[i] cause this is not of the same size (s is a string of several character, string[i] is a string of one character) and s[i] can't be equal to zero cause s[i] isn't a number. The error could be something like that

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  "a bit of a mess" is not a problem specification; it's more of a context-setting phrase for a tutor.

Comment: What are you trying to do by `if s == string[i] and s[i]  == 0` ?

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting: since `s` is a string, no character of `s` is going to compare as equal to zero.  Describe your logic, show your debugging attempts, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to understand your "specification", but try that:

```
string= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
v = 5
s = "dadalasdfg"

for i in string[:v]:
    for j in s:
        if i==j:
           print(j)
           break
```

EDIT: shorter version:

```
string= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
v = 5
s = "dadalasdfg"

for i in string[:5]:
    if i in s:
        print (i)
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are asking. But I assume, if any letter in `s` is present in the first five *alphabets* in `string`, print them.
Your `if` statement will never evaluate to true. You are trying to compare the whole `s` with one alphabet in a string. I think what you are looking for, is something like this:

```
string = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
v = range(5)
s = "dadalasdfg"
for i in v:
    for j in s:
        if j == string[i]:
           print (j)
```

Also, you don't need to declare `v`.
You can do:

```
string = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
s = "dadalasdfg"
for i in range(5):
    for j in s:
        if j == string[i]: #if the particular letter in `string` exists in s
           print (j)
```

If you are looking for the first five *alphabets* that are present in `s`. 
It is pretty much the same thing.

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in s:
      if string[i] == j:
          print(string[i])
          break #comment this out, if you want the result to have repetitions.
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. This was what I needed help for.

Answer (score 0):

For every int `i` in `v`

- if string[i] is  present in s

  - then print string[i]

That is,

```
>>> [string[i] for i in v if string[i] in s]
['a', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>>string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
>>>v = range(5)
>>>s = 'dadalasdfg'
>>>letters = [string[i] for i in v]
>>>letters
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>>found_letters = [i for i in s if i in letters]
>>>found_letters
['d', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading this carefully, I suspect you need something like this:

1. Determine which characters of the alphabet are of interest: the ones whose indices are in your vector.
2. Print the characters of `s` that are "of interest".

   alphabet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
   v = range(5)
   s = "dadalasdfg"

   valid = [alphabet[i] for i in v]
   print [char for char in s if char in valid]

Output:

```
['d', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'd']
```

Note: I changed your variable `string`, because that's also the name of a built-in class.